# BaseGameActivity won't be found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play

I am trying to implement google play services into my game. I've downloaded the BaseGameUtils project from google and imported it into my eclipse workspace. After that I went into my Game's properties and added the BaseGameUtils as library.

Now I expected to be able to use the BaseGameActivity.java class, which is in this folder:

```
BaseGameUtils/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/BaseGameActivity.java
```

Here's an image:

[image]

but when trying to extend my class to a BaseGameActivity it looks like that:

[image]

so, what have I overseen? I really have no idea why it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the "java" directory to be Exported in the Order and Export tab?

Comment: yes but then I keep gettin import errors inside of the BaseGameActivity.class and the other classes

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the code structure out of the "java"directory and into "src".

Comment: Then i will get import errors in every single class of the BaseGameUtils